# What should I write under the heading "Significance of Findings" in my dissertation?

Tags: thesis

I've been writing my dissertation regarding a Rubik's Cube Solver I have developed. I have performed various tests regarding each solving methods' performance and I have created several graphs and such for a "results and analysis" section. I am a bit stuck as I have a chapter called "Discussion" under which is a heading we've been told to cover: "Significance of findings"...

I'm unsure what information I would write here that hasn't been said already?
Any recommendations, thoughts, and ideas are most welcome.

Thank you.

Comment: Color limitations if robot has sight

Comment: If you don't know what to write there, why do you have that section?

Comment: @LouisWaweru I'm not using a robot. It's done through and on the computer.

Comment: @Maeher It's a required section provided by a template we were given... I can't lose marks by writing something rather than nothing

Comment: Explain the significance of your findings, how your solver adds to our understanding of the Rubik’s cube and of AI/optimization techniques, how the methods you developed could be used more broadly to help cure cancer, land on the moon, search for survivors after an earthquake (they always mention that for some reason...), etc etc. Use your creativity and imagination to convince people your findings are significant.

Comment: @DanRomik Your comment should be promoted as an answer since there's not much to add (the heading is self explanatory) other than the OP doesn't (or shouldn't) be too creative, but state what are the implications of the research (choose a faster/better method, find new methods, generalization of the math analysis, etc.). It usually helps to dialogue with the research question here.

Comment: Cheers @DanRomik. I don't think I did a great job at that section but what you said definitely helped!